# Layout PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a layout file as follows

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <ui:insert name="Middle top">
                <h3>This is a Center</h3>
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <ui:insert name="Middle center">
                <h3>This is a Center</h3>
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

But when I run the layout file, nothing is displayed!

I use primefaces 3.5, jsf 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Except center layoutUnit, other layout units must have dimensions defined via size option.

Like this:

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50">
        <h:outputText value="Top content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100">
        <h:outputText value="Bottom content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="300">
        <h:outputText value="Left content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200">
        <h:outputText value="Right Content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:outputText value="Center Content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with a layout concept in your project, it should handle like this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


    <f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       

        <f:metadata>
            <ui:insert name="metadata" />
        </f:metadata>
        <meta  name="selectedLanguage" content="Lang" lang="#{menuBean.selectedLanguage}"/>
        <h:head>
        </head>
        <h:body behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);">
             <p:layout fullPage="true" widgetVar="layoutWdgtMain">

                 <p:layoutUnit id="north" position="north" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                       //enter your code
                 </p:layoutUnit>            
                 <p:layoutUnit id="east" position="east" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      //enter your code
                 </p:layoutUnit>    
                 <p:layoutUnit id="west" position="west" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      //enter your code
                 </p:layoutUnit>            
                <p:layoutUnit id="south" position="south" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     //enter your code
                </p:layoutUnit> 
            </p:layout>
       </h:body>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Layout  component will be deprecated in PF 6.3. Better to switch to plain html 'layout'